# scrapy general parse workflow

Tags: python, scrapy, workflow, yield

I'm new to python and scrapy and wish to understand the methodology.
I have tried the official tutorial on scrapy and followed it but it is only a basic example. My requirement described below is different and only a little more complex.

There is a site which displays Items from a db.
For each Item, I need to take attributes from each individual Item page and the search results (listings) page.
The search results page URL is in the format:

```
    http://example.com/search?&start_index=0
```

Changing *start_index* will change where the results start from.
Only 10 records are displayed per results page.

Results are displayed in table cells in the format:

```
    link | Desc. | Status
```

I need to retrieve Desc. and Status attributes, then follow the link to a page containing more details, which I will also retrieve for Item.
I wish to retrieve a given number of records from any starting index. 
My current method using scrapy is shown below (edited for brevity):

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from cbury_scrapy.items import MyItem

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://example.com/cgi/search?&start_index=",
    ]

    url_index = 0
    URLS_PER_PAGE = 10
    records_remaining = 16
    crawl_done = False

    da = MyItem()        

    def parse(self, response):
        while self.crawl_done != True:
            url = "http://example.com/cgi/search?&start_index=" + str(self.url_index)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_results)
            self.url_index += self.URLS_PER_PAGE


    def parse_results(self, response):
        # Retrieve all table rows from results page
        for row in response.xpath('//table/tr[@class="datrack_resultrow_odd" or @class="datrack_resultrow_even"]'):
            # extract the Description and Status fields

            # extract the link to Item page
            url = r.xpath('//td[@class="datrack_danumber_cell"]//@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)

            if self.records_remaining == 0:
                self.crawl_done = True
                raise CloseSpider('Finished scrape of requested number of records.')

            self.records_remaining -= 1

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # get fields from item page
        # ...   
        yield self.item
```

The code currently does not stop when *records_remaining* reaches 0 and even after throwing *CloseSpider* exception so that is a bug.

I feel this stems from being wrong in how the parsing methods are arranged.
What would be the correct way to structure this in the "scrapy" way?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse(self, response):
    list_of_indexes = response.xpath('place xpath here that leads to a list of urls for indexes')
    for indexes in list_of_indexes:    
        #maybe the urls are only tags ie. ['/extension/for/index1', '/extension/for/index2', etc...]
        index_urls = ['http://domain.com' + index for index in indexes]
        yield scrapy.Request(index_urls, callback = self.parse_indexes)

def parse_index(self, response):
    da = MyItem()
    da['record_date'] = response.xpath('xpath_here')
    da['record_summary'] = response.xpath('xpath_here')
    da['additional_record_info'] = response.xpath('xpath_here')
    yield da
```

This example is over-simplified but I hope it helps.

You want to instantiate your item `da = MyItem()` within the parse itself.

To answer the larger question about parse flow I would start with URLs. Once you find the XPaths for the indexes from the start_url you'll use

```
scrapy.Requests(URL = index_url, callback =parse_indexes)
```

This will direct your spider to the the next parse method parse_indexes.

index_url
 will be drawn from an iteration through the necessary xpaths.

parse_indexes
 will be just like parse but will then draw out the info from the_next_index_url

If this answer is going in the right direction I can post an example later.

Comment: Hello Liam, I have the _da_ item as a member of the _ExampleSpider_ so that all parse methods of the spider have access to it. Do you suggest I pass _da_ to each parse method?
I interpret your answer as recommending collection of all URLs and then following them in a separate parse, which may be a good approach.
I would like to see an example because I am still unclear as to proper practice. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I added an example to my answer. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the example Liam, I should clarify that scraping for da item begins on the search results page because the fields provided (Desc. and Status) only appear in each row on the search results page (not inside each individual record page unfortunately).
I therefore see da instantiated on the first pass, collecting link, Desc. and Status.
A second pass can then follow the links and request individual item pages, filling remaining fields.

Comment: I found the scrapy way of passing data between parse methods here:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions